# Guava Lazy Collection using Supplier interface

Tags: java, collections, guava

I would like some kind of generic method to allow me to lazy load a collections contents based on use of the java.util.Collection.get( int ) method. I found the Supplier interface in Guava and this looks like a great way of doing the lazy loading, but how to make the loading invisible in java collections is something I am struggling with.

Below is a sample lazy loading method that iterates through an iterator.

```
class MySupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {
    private T s;
    public MySupplier( T s ) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public T get() {
        System.out.println( String.format( "Lazy loading '%s'", s ) );
        return s;
    }
}

public void lazyLoad() {
    List<MySupplier<String>> list = Lists.newArrayList( new MySupplier<String>( "a" ), new MySupplier<String>( "a" ), new MySupplier<String>( "b" ), new MySupplier<String>( "c" ), new MySupplier<String>( "d" ) );
    for ( Iterator<MySupplier<String>> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        System.out.println( i.next().get() );
    }
}
```

I want to avoid having to use the Supplier.get() method if I can help it, but instead have a collections wrapper take care of it for me when Collection.get( int ) is called. I hope to achieve this in a simple method call that I called `makeLazy( Collection )` below.

```
public void lazyLoad_desired() {
    List<String> list = makeLazy( 
            Lists.newArrayList( new MySupplier<String>( "a" ), new MySupplier<String>( "a" ), new MySupplier<String>( "b" ), new MySupplier<String>( "c" ), new MySupplier<String>( "d" ) )
        );
    for ( Iterator<String> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        String s = i.next();
        System.out.println( s );
    }
}
```

I realise that I would need to override collections somehow, but my knowledge in this area has some gaps. Could somebody give me some hints and tips on what I need to do to implement the makeLazy( Collection ) method?

Thanks,
Stuart

Comment: In what sort of context do you need this?  Do you actually have reason to believe this would give a performance benefit?

Comment: Yes. We have scenarios in our EJB application where this could save time as instead of loading all query results, it only loads those required. Some queries can return hundreds of locals, but we might only be interested in the first three or four.

Comment: Generally speaking, youre better off doing this as an Iterable than a Collection, which avoids much of the mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion with [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) I decided to take his advice and use an iterator. The solution below appears to be working for me.

```
class MySupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {
    private T s;
    public MySupplier( T s ) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public T get() {
        System.out.println( String.format( "Lazy loading '%s'", s ) );
        return s;
    }
}

public void lazyLoad() {
    List<MySupplier<String>> list = Lists.newArrayList( new MySupplier<String>( "a" ), new MySupplier<String>( "a" ), new MySupplier<String>( "b" ), new MySupplier<String>( "c" ), new MySupplier<String>( "d" ) );

    for ( Iterator<String> i = supplierIterator( list ); i.hasNext(); ) {
        System.out.println( i.next() );
    }
}

public static <T> Iterator<T> supplierIterator( Collection<? extends Supplier<T>> c ) {
    Function<Supplier<T>, T> function = Suppliers.supplierFunction();
    Iterable<T> iterable = Iterables.transform( c, function );
    return iterable.iterator();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this.